# How to define input and result as DataTable in specs2?

Tags: scala, testing, specs2

I was trying to use DataTables in specs2 to define both input and how the result should look like and could not get it to work. I was thinking something similar to the below code:

```
class MySpec extends Specification with DataTables {

"A Container" should {
"after data is added container should have the following data" in new TestContainer {
  "a"  | "flag" | "d"   |
  100  ! 1      ! "abc" |
  300  ! 1      ! "abc" |
  200  ! 0      ! "xyz" |>
  { (a, flag, d) =>
    container.add(Data(a, flag, d)) must not(throwA[Exception])
  } and
  "a"  | "flag" | "d"   |
  300  ! 1      ! "abc" |
  100  ! 1      ! "abc" |>
  { (a, flag, d) => ????
  }
}
}
```

Disclaimer: I am new to scala and specs. Some of the code was omitted for brevity.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what is not working?

Comment: I cannot find a simple way to compare a state of the container after I add data from the first DataTable with second DataTable. Second DataTable shows what container.list() should return.

Comment: Why don't you put all data in one table: both inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: This will work if I add another column indicating if the row  is a result or an input. This approach won't work if data format of input and result are different.

Comment: I meant having both the input values and the expected outputs for a given call on the same row.

Comment: This won't work. Container might drop some of input rows when they are added plus I am concerned with the order of results irrespective of the order the input rows were added.

Comment: I am looking for something similar to Data Table diffing in Cucumber http://cukes.info/step-definitions.html. Just search for "Data Table diffing".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After gaining better understanding of specs2 here is a solution I came up with:

```
class MySpec extends Specification with DataTables {

"A Container" should {
"after data is added container should have the following data" in new TestContainer {
  "a"  | "flag" | "d"   |
  100  ! 1      ! "abc" |
  300  ! 1      ! "abc" |
  200  ! 0      ! "xyz" |>
  { (a, flag, d) =>
    container.add(Data(a, flag, d)) must not(throwAn[Exception])
  }
  val state = container.list
  "a"  | "flag" | "d"   |
  300  ! 1      ! "abc" |
  100  ! 1      ! "abc" |>
  { (a, flag, d) => state must contain((a, flag, d))
  }
}
}
```

If order is important then second table can add tuples to some list and then compare 2 lists after second table is processed. Please, note this behavior is broken in 2.3, but works in 2.4-SNAPSHOT.